# Why can I use Maven plugins without declaring them in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have a pom.xml **without** declaring the `versions-maven-plugin`

```
<!-- no need to declare this in my pom.xml, plugin still works -->
<plugin>
    <!-- https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/ -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
</plugin>
```

When using `mvn versions:display-property-updates`, the plugin works even if I did not include the plugin in my `pom.xml`. Are all plugins from code *org.codehaus.mojo* already included in the maven distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the default `settings.xml` file that ships with Maven](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.6.3/apache-maven/src/conf/settings.xml#L73-L77), you will see:

> **pluginGroups**
>
> This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e. when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". **Maven will automatically add the group identifiers "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.**

You can see the effective settings with:

```
$ mvn help:effective-settings
```

If you want to add additional groups, you can do so in your local `settings.xml` (by default located at `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- Add stackoverflow maven plugins -->
    <pluginGroup>com.stackoverflow.plugins</plugingroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Comment: I only use the default `settings.xml`, I did not include anything by myself. Does your anwer mean that `versions-maven-plugin` is **automatically included** without defining this plugin in my `pom.xml` because the **effective-settings** includes `<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>`.

Comment: Yes, read the quoted section above. Maven adds it automatically.